# Is playing with a water gun allowed

Tags: halacha, water, games-toys, bal-tashchit-waste

Is playing with a water gun for fun allowed or is it a problem of [baal tashchis](http://www.teach613.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=236&Itemid=54) (wasting resources)?
(assuming for adult playing with kids or with other adults)

This is really a general question of where do you draw the line between recreation and baal tashchit.

Comment: Is having a pool Baal Tashchit?

Comment: right good point. where do you draw the line though?

Comment: Especially in Israel.

Comment: @ray so essentially that's your question. If I were you I would change it (but that's why I'm not you:))

Comment: Very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/filmmaking-bal-tashchis (This would probably be a duplicate if I had worded mine more broadly.)

Comment: I think the issue of baal tashchis is completely relative... I could be wrong though. That's just how I remember it.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12933/is-runoff-water-from-a-drinking-fountain-a-problem-of-bal-tashhith?rq=1#comment83900_12942